# What did I do wrong with this subquery for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I've got a table called tblEventLocationStock.  It stores sales information for stock at a certain location and event.  I'm trying to get a list of items that have a different starting count than the end count from the previous event.  I've got this query, but I get the "subquery returned more than 1 value" error:

```
SELECT ID,EventID,LocationID,StockID,StartQty,UnitPrice,PhysicalSalesQty,PhysicalSalesValue,PhysicalEndQty,TillSoldQty,TillSoldValue
FROM   tblEventLocationStock ELS
where StartQty <> (
    select PhysicalEndQty from tblEventLocationStock ELSO
        where ELS.StockID=ELSO.StockID
        and ELS.LocationID=ELSO.LocationID
        and ELS.EventID=(ELSO.EventID+1000))
        ORDER BY ID desc
```

I use ELS.EventID=ELSO.EventID+1000 because the event ID's go up in intervals of 1000.

What's odd is that even though I get the "subquery returned more than 1 value" error, I still get 10 rows in the results tab.  Those 10 results do appear to have a different starting count for the items than the same item at the same location from the previous event.  Also, I get no results if I use an order by, but I still get 10 results if I don't use an order by.

What's even more odd is that I get those 10 results if I run the query with some joins to some other tables so I can get names of the stock items and locations instead of just IDs, but if I do it without the joins, I get no results.

Comment: Why you can use NOT EXISTS instead of '<>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,

```
SELECT ID, EventID, LocationID, StockID, StartQty, UnitPrice, PhysicalSalesQty,
       PhysicalSalesValue, PhysicalEndQty, TillSoldQty, TillSoldValue
FROM tblEventLocationStock ELS
WHERE NOT EXISTS  (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tblEventLocationStock ELSO
    WHERE ELS.StockID    = ELSO.StockID        AND
          ELS.StartQty  <> ELSO.PhysicalEndQty AND
          ELS.LocationID = ELSO.LocationID     AND
          ELS.EventID    = (ELSO.EventID+1000)
)
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, that works!  I'll have to read up on the proper ways to use subqueries.

Comment: What would be the difference between

`WHERE NOT EXISTS  (
SELECT 1
FROM tblEventLocationStock ELSO
     WHERE 
          ELS.StartQty  = ELSO.PhysicalEndQty AND
          ELS.EventID    = (ELSO.EventID+1000)`

and

`WHERE EXISTS  (
     SELECT 1
     FROM tblEventLocationStock ELSO
     WHERE ELS.StartQty  <> ELSO.PhysicalEndQty AND
                   ELS.EventID    = (ELSO.EventID+1000)`